# Solution of $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$ and $z^2 +y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $X = Z_1 \cap Z_1$ with $Z_{1}=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\right\}, \quad Z_{2}=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1\right\}$.
I would like to determine $X$. From $x^2 + y^2  \leq  1 \rightarrow x^2 \leq 1 -y^2$ we have that $-1 \leq y \leq 1$.  The solution says that $ -\sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x,z \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}$.

I understand the upper bound, but don't see how to get to the lower bound

Comment: How did you can understand the upper bound without understand the lower bound?

Comment: @NN2 Because from $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \rightarrow x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}$ i only see why $-\sqrt{1-y^2} \leq -x$ holds, but not why $-\sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x$ holds.

Comment: $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, so $x^2 \le 1-y^2$. Hence $|x| \le \sqrt{1-y^2}$

Comment: @AnnaSaabel I guess that is because $x$ could be negative as well (as NN2 has shown $|x| \leq \sqrt{1 - y^2}$). $a < b \implies -a > -b$. Keeping that in mind, if you take $-x \geq \sqrt{1 - y^2}$, you can say $x \geq -\sqrt{1 - y^2}$. Know that for both positive and negative $x$, the square is always positive.

Comment: Just what I got from a quick look - I am not as high level as you all are , and I commented as above at somewhere near midnight (a time when I am least aware)

Comment: Please point out to me if I am wrong :)